# Delegate declared in UIView subclass won't work in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to create a reusable UIView that I can place in multiple UIViewControllers. I gave it delegate methods that I want the parent UIViewControllers to access, but it throws me an error (commented in the code below). What's a better way I can solve this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: CameraView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.cameraView.delegate = self
        //ERROR: Cannot assign a value of type 'viewController' to a value of type 'CameraViewDelegate?'
    }
}

protocol CameraViewDelegate {
    func cameraViewShutterButtonTapped()
    func cameraViewimagePickerTapped(imageData: NSData)
}
class CameraView: UIView {    
    var delegate:CameraViewDelegate?
    //Ect...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not specified that `ViewController` conforms to the `CameraViewDelegate` protocol. You should amend your code to this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CameraViewDelegate {
```

…at which point Xcode will complain that you have not implemented `cameraViewShutterButtonTapped()` and `cameraViewimagePickerTapped()`, which at least tells you that you're on the right track!

Side note: do you really want the camera view to have a strong reference to its delegate? You might want that to be `weak`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now. I didn't think that error was because I wasn't conforming to the protocol, but it was! I'm learning as I go, so I didn't even consider the difference between a strong and weak reference to the delegate. I'll read into this for sure

Comment: Good to hear! I think it's fair to say that Swift's error messages are still in need of some refinement :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to have your ViewController class implement the CameraViewDelegate protocol, like so:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, CameraViewDelegate { ... }
```